# Can a Regex without characters [(+*{}? be dangerous?

Tags: regex

I want to create some functionality for non dangerous regex.
I want to accept only very few regex cases where it is safe to assume that they are not malicious (but still giving the user some flexibility).

Is this possible avoiding the `[(+*{}?` characters?

Comment: How do you define a dangerous regex?

Comment: @Cowthulhu  check this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: That is super interesting - learn something new every day! It would probably help to edit that into your question so it's all in one spot.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to filter with the regex. It might not be possible without those characters. You're probably better off trying to sanitize the user input to prevent DOS attacks.